# finding big theta notation with recursion and nlg(n)

Tags: computational-complexity

given the recursion formula: $T(n) = T(n-1) + n\cdot \lg{n}$ I need to find $g(n)$ so that $T(n)=\theta(g(n))$. I know that $T(n) = n\cdot \lg n + (n-1)\cdot \lg (n-1) + (n-2)\cdot \lg (n-2 + ... = \sum_{i=2}^{n}i\cdot \lg{n} + \theta(1) \le n^2\cdot\lg{n} + \theta(1)\Longrightarrow T(n)=O(n^2\cdot\lg{n})$ but I can't find a way to prove $T(n)=\Omega(n^2\cdot\lg{n})$ and I don't see another function that can be $g(n)$ other than $n^2\cdot\lg{n}$

Comment: That same sum you have, estimate it from $i=n/2$ to $n$. Each of the $n/2$ terms is then at least $(n/2) \operatorname{lg}{n/2}  = \Omega (n \operatorname{lg}(n))$.

Comment: but I can't prove $T(n)=O(n\cdot\lg{n})$ so $T(n)\notin\theta(n\cdot\lg{n})$

Comment: The result is then  $ \sum\limits_{i=n/2}^n   \Theta (n \lg n) = \Theta (n^2 \lg n)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $T(n) = \sum\limits_{i=2}^n i \lg i + \Theta(1)$, we have
$$
T(n) > O(n)+ \sum\limits_{i=n/2}^n i \lg i > O(n) + \sum\limits_{i=n/2}^{n} \frac{n}{2} \lg \frac{n}{2} > O(n)+ \sum\limits_{i=n/2}^n \Omega( n \lg n) = O(n) + \Omega(n^2 \lg n).
$$
Basically, the sum included at least roughly $n/2$ summands that exceed $n/2 \lg (n/2) > (n \lg n)/2 + O(n)$